# Is Thread.CurrentThread unique per request?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let's say that I have two .net MVC controller endpoints that are called in parallel. Is `Thread.CurrentThread` unique per request? My concern is that I'm changing `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` in a specific endpoint, and I don't want it to affect any other methods that could be called in parallel.

To elaborate what I'm doing: I have a view model class that uses a third party library to generate its multilingual properties. In order to figure out what language the properties should be presented in, the library checks `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`.

It does provide an alternative solution where I can pass in explicit cultures for each property, so I guess that's an approach to avoid fiddling with the thread culture.

Here is the plugin: https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/vorto/

Comment: What do you mean by `in parallel`? Do you mean two web requests that are occurring at the same time? Talk us through why you believe you need to change `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`.

Comment: *Don't* change the culture instead, use the overloads that accept a culture.

Comment: A thread can't run more than one thing at a time. As long as you're only changing (and *restoring*) the culture in one sequential block, you're fine. Otherwise, you're not fine -- if you `await` something, the thread is free to go do something else. Ideally, consider rewriting things so you don't need the UI culture, by passing the culture info explicitly to any methods that could be influenced by them.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have updated the question. Yes, I suppose that's cleaner. The problem in my case is that I would have to handle this on property level, instead of per request level (see update for details).

Comment: @filur - sounds like you need to create some kind of "context" class that wraps all access to the third party library but also allows you to just set a culture on it once, which you can then put into your DI container as a per-request basis. The methods it exposes won't talk about culture but will call the appropriate versions in the library that do specify it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've just created an overload to the models which takes a culture parameter and uses it for its properties. If it's not specified it'll fallback to the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`